# Was bedeutet "bei dir" in "klappt's heute bei dir?"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Wie der Titel schon erkennen lässt, was bedeutet "bei dir" in "klappt's heute bei dir?" ?

Normalerweise drückt "bei jemandem" Räumlichkeit aus, d.h. bei jemandem zuhause z.B.
Könnte es im o.g. Beispiel bedeuten: "gelingt es dir heute, zu kommen?" ?

Vielen Dank

Comment: Dein Beispiel ist unglücklich gewählt. Wenn jemand irgendwohin *kommt*, ist das normalerweise gerade nicht bei ihm zuhause.

Comment: Mit der Bedeutung an sich liegst du allerdings völlig richtig. "Bei dir" kann grob gesagt nicht nur wörtlich ("in deiner Nähe"), sondern auch im übertragenen Sinn ("was dich betrifft/von dir ausgeht") verwendet werden.

Comment: @Annatar Wieso ist es gerade nicht bei jemandem zu Hause? „Wann kommst du nach Hause?“ ist eine oft gestellte, natürlich klingende Frage.

Comment: @Philipp Anderer Kontext. Hier ging es um die Frage "Klappt's heute bei dir?", die mit "Gelingt es dir heute zu kommen?" umschrieben werden soll. Zweiteres ist schwer mit einem Treffpunkt bei demjenigen zuhause zu vereinbaren. ;)

Comment: Etwas mehr Kontext wäre tatsächlich sehr hilfreich, denn das Verb *»kommen«* kann auch bedeuten: *»einen Orgasmus haben«*. Dann lassen sich sowohl *»klappt's heute bei dir?«* als auch *»gelingt es dir heute, zu kommen?«* als Fragen nach der Fähigkeit deuten, einen Orgasmus zu erleben.

Comment: @Annatar Stimmt.

Answer (score 5):

Einerseits kann damit ein räumlicher Bezug gemeint sein, sprich, "...heute bei dir (zuhause;auf Arbeit;...)?"
In dem Kontext kenne ich es aber eher selten, meistens wird damit einfach Bezug auf die Person genommen und der Satz schlicht und ergreifend verkürzt, aber ohne, dass der Sinn für alle Gesprächsteilnehmer verloren geht.

"Klappt's heute bei dir?" gibt es daher auch in vielen anderen Varianten
Passt es dir heute?
Schaffst du es denn um 18 Uhr?
Kannst du es zeitlich einrichten?

Im Groben kann man es als Umgangssprache werten.

Comment: +1 Besser und ausführlicher als meine Antwort.

Comment: Danke für die Blumen. :-)

Answer (score 2):

"Klappt es heute zeitlich bei dir" wäre das ganze meiner Meinung nach als ausgeschriebener Satz.

Wie aber auch immer im deutschen: Es kommt auf den Bezug an. 
Aber primär wird das Ganze so genutzt - nur um eben nochmal "abzuklopfen" ob der Termin/die Abmachung noch steht/wie geplant durchgeführt wird.